# Error while connecting to local DB using Ruby ROM with Sinatra

Tags: sinatra

I'm fairly new to Sinatra and trying to connect to my database and using Ruby ROM gem for this. However, I'm always getting the following error message when I'm trying to execute my rake task:
`ArgumentError: URIs without an explicit scheme are not supported anymore.`

Here is my Rakefile:

```
require_relative './config/environment'
require 'rom/sql/rake_task'

namespace :db do
  task :setup do
    configuration = ROM::Configuration.new(:sql, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
    ROM::SQL::RakeSupport.env = configuration
  end
end
```

And this my .env.development while where I've placed my database URL

```
DATABASE_URL='postgres://username:password@localhost/convertor_dev'
```

I'm using the following gems(if this helps):

- rom
- rom-sql
- pg
- rake

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after some research, I found that `ROM::Configuration.new(:sql, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])` internally calls `Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])`. Therefore, a quick fix around this will be like this:

```
connection = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
configuration = ROM::Configuration.new(:sql, connection)
```